# why is my index.html file returning a blank screen whenever i debug or preview it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

this is the app.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import DashboardLayout from './layouts/DashboardLayout';
import './faithdash/scss/styles.scss';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route component={DashboardLayout} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

```html
this is the index.html file
ive tried everything and have used different my vscode index chrome previewer to view the index file like others but its shows a blank screen


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Faithpays dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png" />
    <link
      href="https://%PUBLIC_URL%/evergreen.eot"
      rel="font"
    />
    <link
      href="https://%PUBLIC_URL%/evergreen.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      crossorigin="anonymous" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="_nav.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't call render function from ReactDOM.

See more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html